# Explicit map between $\check{H}^1(M,\underline{\mathbb{R}})$ and $H^1(M,\mathbb{R})$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, sheaf-theory

Is there a way to construct an explicit isomorphism between Cech cohomology and singular cohomology for degree 1? If yes can this be extended to higher degee?

Comment: You might find the comments here useful: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/310306/outline-of-the-proof-that-cech-cohomology-and-singular-cohomology-coincide-on-an . You could probably unwind the relevant spectral sequence to get an explicit isomorphism, but I don't think there's any real benefit in doing so.

Comment: What is $M$? An arbitrary space?

Comment: @PaulFrost Yes, a smooth manifold

Comment: @BinAcker I will assume that answering "Yes, a smooth manifold." to "Is $M$ an *arbitrary* space?" is intended a good humour!